# AspNetCore 1.1 Group By and Count gets an object

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have the following table:

Cans 
Id: int 
HospitalId: (Foreign Key) int 
operDt: DateTime

I need to calculate the total number of cans rows grouped by hospitalId

to get a simillar result without Id
[image]
The repository :

```
 public Task GetCansMin(DateTime startdt, DateTime enddt)
        {
            using (appContext)
            {
                return appContext.Cans.Where(c => c.OperDt > startdt && c.OperDt < enddt).GroupBy(c => c.HospitalId)
                      .Select(g => new
                      {
                          NumberofCancelled = g.Count() 
                      }).ToArrayAsync();

            };
        }
```

The controller:

```
 [HttpGet("bydate")]
        public IActionResult GetCanMin(DateTime startdt, DateTime endd)
        {
            var res = this._unitOfWork.Cans.GetCansMin(startdt, endd);
            return Ok(res);
        }
```

When passing the request with postman:

http://localhost:56964/api/cansdatas/bydate?startdt=2016-01-01&enddt=2016-12-31

instead of receiving an array of results I get an empty object....
Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

Since the method you're calling is async, you need to await the Task returned.

```
    [HttpGet("bydate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCanMin(DateTime startdt, DateTime endd)
    {
        var res = await this._unitOfWork.Cans.GetCansMin(startdt, endd);
        return Ok(res);
    }
```

Comment: To accept the async method, i changed the repository to   public async Task<object> GetCansMin(DateTime startdt, DateTime enddt)
        {
            using (appContext)
            {
                return await appContext.Cans.Where(c => c.OperDt > startdt && c.OperDt < enddt).GroupBy(c => c.HospitalId)
                      .Select(g => new
                      {
                          NumberofCancelled = g.Count() 
                      }).ToArrayAsync();
                     
            };
        }     Error, cannot assign void to implicitly types variable

Comment: Ah, that's right. But that solved it for you? The error was before this fix, right?

Answer (score 0):

A view model created

```
 public class CancelledCan
    {
        public int HospitalId { get; set; }

        public int NumberofCancelled { get; set; }
    }
```

Change the repository to to

```
public async Task<List<CancelledCan>> GetCansMin(DateTime startdt, DateTime enddt)
        {
            using (appContext)
            {
                return await appContext.Cans.Where(c => c.OperDt > startdt && c.OperDt < enddt).GroupBy(c => c.HospitalId).OrderBy(c=>c.Count())
                      .Select(g => new CancelledCan
                      {
                          HospitalId = g.Key,
                          NumberofCancelled = g.Count() 
                      }).ToListAsync();
            };
        }
```